# changing select_tag to f.select in implementing dependent dropdowns in Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make a dropdown list for subcategories that depend on the initial category you picked. For this I utilized [this link](http://www.devinterface.com/blog/en/2013/12/come-implementare-in-rails-4-delle-dropdown-dipendenti-con-script-jquery-non-intrusivo/). It works well here

```
    <p><%= f.select :category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.parent_categories.all, "id", "title"), :prompt => "Select a Category" %></p>
<p><%= select_tag :subcat_id, options_from_collection_for_select([], "id", "title"),
                 "data-option-dependent" => true,
                 "data-option-observed" => "product_category_id",
                 "data-option-url" => "/categories/:category_id:/subcategories.json",
                 "data-option-key-method" => :id,
                 "data-option-value-method" => :title %></p>
```

Here is the jquery code-

```
     $jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('select[data-option-dependent=true]').each(function (i) {
        var observer_dom_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var observed_dom_id = $(this).data('option-observed');
        var url_mask = $(this).data('option-url');
        var key_method = $(this).data('option-key-method');
        var value_method = $(this).data('option-value-method');
        var prompt = $(this).has("option[value='']").size() ? $(this).find("option[value='']") : $('<option value=\"\">').text('Select a subcategory');
        var regexp = /:[0-9a-zA-Z_]+:/g;
        var observer = $('select#' + observer_dom_id);
        var observed = $('#' + observed_dom_id);

        if (!observer.val() && observed.size() > 1) {
            observer.attr('disabled', true);
        }
        observed.on('change', function () {
            observer.empty().append(prompt);
            if (observed.val()) {
                url = url_mask.replace(regexp, observed.val());
                $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, object) {
                        observer.append($('<option>').attr('value', object[key_method]).text(object[value_method]));
                        observer.attr('disabled', false);
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

However then I cannot upload a product to that category because it must have f.select. There is no f.select_tag and when I use f.select the dependent dropdown stops working. So how would I rewrite this

```
<p><%= f.select :subcat_id, options_from_collection_for_select([], "id", "title"),
"data-option-dependent" => true,
"data-option-observed" => "product_category_id",
"data-option-url" => "/categories/:category_id:/subcategories.json",
"data-option-key-method" => :id,
"data-option-value-method" => :title %>    
</p>
```

to make it work for f.select? Additionally this is my first question I hope I wrote it ok.

Comment: What is the error you're getting when you say the dependent dropdown isn't working?

Comment: No error is shown just no data is being filled in the select dropdown. While with select tag there is data being filled.